# Execute template fragment in main template based on requested URL

Tags: go, go-templates

Not sure how to name this correctly.

Is there any way to write one main template and many fragments and inject required fragment based on URL user requests.
Let's say i have **/customers/profile** and **/customers/projects**. I want to write one main **customer.html** template file and one **customer-includes.html** file with 2 **{{ define "profile" }}** and **{{ define "projects" }}** fragments.
Then i want have 2 handlers to handle **/customers/profile** and **/customers/projects** and to execute **customer.html** template.
But, when user go to the URL **/customers/profile** i want to inject in main template **{{ template "profile" . }}** and if he goes to **/customers/projects** i want to inject **{{ template "projects" . }}**.
What is the best way to do this?
I assume i need to use some kind of {{ if / else }} there. As example below. But mby there is better way.

```
        {{ if ( eq .Section "customer-profile") }} // Could be replaced with Page ID
            {{ template "profile" . }}
            {{ else }}
            {{ template "projects" . }}
        {{ end}}
```

Comment: Looks like you want generic HandlerFunc parameterized with URL path. Personally, I don't think it's a good idea. For me this make code more verbose and fragile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use template blocks for this.

`templates/customers-base.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{.title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/styles.css">
    <!-- You can include common scripts and stylesheets in the base template -->
</head>
<body>
{{block "BODY" .}}

{{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

`templates/customers-projects.html`:

```
{{define "BODY"}}

<h1>Your Projects</h1>
<p>Normal template goes here</p>
<p>{{.myvar}}<p>

{{end}}
```

You can copy this format for `templates/customers-profile.html`.

Your project code:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{
    "title": "Base template example",
    "myvar": "Variable example",
}

layoutCustomersBase     := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/customers-base.html"))
layoutCustomersProjects := template.Must(layoutCustomersBase.ParseFiles("templates/customers-projects.html"))
// Or layoutCustomersProfile, if you are parsing in the '/customers/profile' handler. 

err := layoutError.Execute(w, data)
```

Notice that you can define the "title" variable when you execute the `customers-projects` template; it will be used in the base template.

Comment: My initial idea was about implementing "Tab" panel in those pages. In case of one URL i load Profile tab content and in case of other - Projects tab content.
This way i could minimize amount of template files for every tab because currently already i have 10 tabs JUST for Customer page. And in your example this means 10 additional template files.
But i will think about it. Mby it is not good idea i had to append all {{ define ... }} fragments in one file.
Thank you for idea about Blocks.